# Use of svg files as image in google drive site

Tags: image, svg, include, google-drive-api

I've noticed that websites made in google drive (shared public folder)
can't use svg as image.

Is it a security restriction ?

so this code don't show the image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG as image</title>
</head>
<body>

     <img src="the_image.svg">

</body>
</html>
```

online example

https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwRlR3z6e0egbXM3clR1ZEFaM00/svg_as_image.html

Answer (score 0):

Google is returning the file as MIME type "text/xml" rather than the "image/svg+xml" it should be.  You could try requesting Google fix that.

In the meantime, try using an object instead.

```
<object data="the_image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

You might have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot !

it helped me

the mimetype of the svg file saved with janvas (janvas.com) whose "text/xml"

this example use a svg file saved on google drive with the right mymetype "image/svg+xml"

works !

https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwRlR3z6e0egbXM3clR1ZEFaM00/svg_as_image_right_mimetype.html

Answer (score 0):

You can insert svg images on sites.google using the "insert code" tool to insert the svg code. When you there, just open your svg in a text editor, copy the entire svg code and paste it on your insert code as I show in this images.

[site google svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EddMp.png)

[site google svg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vNWK.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).